# dynamic_cast fails for an object whose dynamic type is the casted type

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I am pretty sure this is a compiler bug or something: if two types in different translation units have the same name and derive from nested classes of a template class, dynamic_cast will fail in one of those translation units.

In my case, I use two different types named `A` in two translation units (they were test cases). In each, I have an object `obj` of type `A`. `A` is derived from an abstract base `root_type`. `obj_ref` has type `root_type&` and is bound to `obj`. Attempting to cast `obj_ref` to `A&` throws `std::bad_cast`.

*mixin.hpp*

```
#pragma once
template <typename... Types>
struct mixin
{
    struct root_type
    {
        virtual ~root_type() = default;
    };
};
```

*use_AB.cpp*

```
#include "mixin.hpp"
struct A;
struct B;
struct A : mixin<A, B>::root_type{};

void use_AB()
{
    using root_type = mixin<A, B>::root_type;
    A a;
    root_type &a_ref = a;
    dynamic_cast<A&>(a_ref);
}
```

*use_A.cpp*

```
#include "mixin.hpp"
struct A;
struct A : mixin<A>::root_type {};

void use_A()
{
    using root_type = mixin<A>::root_type;
    A a;
    root_type &a_ref = a;
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    dynamic_cast<A&>(a_ref); // throws - dynamic_cast failure
    //////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
void use_A();
void use_AB();

int main()
{
    use_A();
    use_AB();
    return 0;
}
```

What’s going on?

Compiler is VisualStudio 2015 (v140).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Barry still minimizing the repro

Comment: No you should provide code for type `A` and `root_type` because if `root_type` is not polymorphic then `dynamic_cast` can't be used.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès root_type is abstract which implies that both are polymorphic

Comment: *"I am intentionally leaving out details..."* why would you do this?

Comment: @Barry @JohnathanPotter The error goes away when I copy the code into a different namespace. Since I can't even reliably reproduce the error by copying code on my own computer, I cannot give an example which I would call verifiable. That aside, the implementation of `root_type` and `A` are not relevant to my question, which is whether (given the assertions which I make) the cast **could** throw. Can it?

Comment: @Kietz Clearly they're relevant to the question. If you can't reproduce the error, then you have an incorrect perception of what the problem is.

Comment: He he, `volatile`. Andrei Alexandrescu used to do that, or at least discussed it, as I recall, with `volatile` as a kind of type checked **tag**.

Comment: **unable to reproduce** with Visual C++ 2015 update 2, with or without exception or RTTI enabled.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf could you try again with at least two different `cpp` files?

Comment: @Kietz: No need. After you posted the more Real Code™ you have an answer already, an ODR violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You violate the One Definition Rule by giving `struct A` two different definitions:

```
struct A : mixin<A, B>::root_type{};
struct A : mixin<A>::root_type {};
```

Therefore your program has undefined behavior, and the compiler is not required to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I'll put those classes in `namespace {}` in the future (that should fix it, right?). I'm still surprised the compiler didn't give me any error, though...

Comment: @Kietz: How would it detect this error? Different translation units are translated completely independently. This is the reason the standard does not require detection of this violation,

Comment: Sorry, then I mean a linker error

Comment: On reflection, there is no way a linker error could be generated unless the linker examined the two `A` classes for equivalence, which is a crazy thing to expect